# CSRF error after create entity POST request in ABAP OData service

Tags: post, odata, csrf, abap, sap-gateway

I am about to learning OData Services in ABAP for working purposes.
Implementing the create entity request I run into some issues.

```
METHOD airportsset_create_entity.

****************************************************
* VARIABLES
****************************************************

    DATA:
      lt_wa_input_data LIKE er_entity,
      lt_wa_airport    TYPE zt_xy_airport,
      lv_max_id        TYPE zd_xy_id.

****************************************************
* METHOD LOGIC
****************************************************

    " Get the data from the post request body.
    CALL METHOD io_data_provider->read_entry_data
      IMPORTING
        es_data = lt_wa_airport.

    " Copy data into the work area.
    MOVE-CORRESPONDING lt_wa_input_data TO lt_wa_airport.

    " Select the max id from the table to prevent duplicate key error.
    SELECT SINGLE MAX( airport_id ) FROM zt_xy_airport INTO lv_max_id.

    " Fill out the remaining fields of the work area.
    lt_wa_airport-mandt = sy-mandt.
    lt_wa_airport-airport_id = lv_max_id + 1.

    " Insert the data to the table.
    INSERT zt_kd_airport FROM lt_wa_airport.

  ENDMETHOD.
```

Calling this POST request I got back this error:

> CSRF token validation failed

I know that I have to get the token from a get request header, but when I try to insert that token into the POST request header nothing seem to be working. Got back the same error.

I am working in SAP LOGON 770.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POST request must be preceded by a HEAD request to the same endpoint (or a GET request to the service's base URL) which includes the header

```
X-CSRF-Token: Fetch
```

The response to this HEAD (or GET) request will then contain a CSRF token in the `X-CSRF-Token` header, and it will contain

- a session cookie `SAP_SESSIONID_<SID>_<client>`, to which this token is bound,
- or, if there is no session, a `sap-XSRF_<SID>_<client>` cookie, to which this token is bound.

Whether there is a session depends on the authentication mechanism that you chose. But in any case, both the cookie and the `X-CSRF-Token` header must be included in the POST request.

Likely, you have to make a change in the code that *makes* the request (which you have not shared).

Comment: Thank. The Cookie was the problem. I send the wrong one.